# Disabling buttons in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing some Shiny code where the user will enter some inputs to the app and then click a an action button.  The action button triggers a bunch of simulations to run that take a long time so I want once the action button is clicked for it to be disabled so that the user can't keep clicking it until the simulations are run. I came across the `shinyjs::enable` and `shinyjs::disable` functions but have been having a hard time utilizing them.  Here is my server code:

```
output$button1= renderUI({
        if(input$Button1 > 0)  {
          shinyjs::disable("Button1")
                tableOutput("table")
          shinyjs::enable("Button1")}
  })
```

However, when I use this code, and click the action button nothing happens. I.e., teh action button doesn't grey out nor does the table get generated.  However, when I take away the `shinyjs::enable()` command, i.e.,

```
    output$button1= renderUI({
            if(input$Button1 > 0)  {
              shinyjs::disable("Button1")
                    tableOutput("table")
}
      })
```

The table gets generated first, and then the button goes grey, however I would have expected the button to go grey and then the table to generate itself.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Here is my updated code based on Geovany's suggestion yet it still doesn't work for me**

```
Button1Ready <- reactiveValues(ok = FALSE)

        observeEvent(input$Button1,  {
          shinyjs::disable("Button1")
          RunButton1Ready$ok <- FALSE
          RunButton1Ready$ok <- TRUE
  })

output$SumUI1= renderUI({
        if(Button1Ready$ok){
          tableOutput("table")
          shinyjs::enable("Button1")
        }
})
```

where for clarification I have also:

```
output$table <- renderTable({

#My code....

)}
```

Answer (score 26):

I think that you are using `shinyjs::disable` and `shinyjs::enable` in the same reactive function. You will only see the last effect. I will recommend you to split in different reactive functions the `disable/enable` and use an extra reactive variable to control the reactivation of the button.

I don't know how exactly your code is, but in the code below the main idea is illustrated.

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("Button1", "Run"),
      shinyjs::hidden(p(id = "text1", "Processing..."))
    ),
    mainPanel(
       plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  plotReady <- reactiveValues(ok = FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$Button1, {
    shinyjs::disable("Button1")
    shinyjs::show("text1")
    plotReady$ok <- FALSE
    # do some cool and complex stuff
    Sys.sleep(2)
    plotReady$ok <- TRUE
  })  

  output$plot <-renderPlot({
    if (plotReady$ok) {
      shinyjs::enable("Button1")
      shinyjs::hide("text1")
      hist(rnorm(100, 4, 1),breaks = 50)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Geovany, I updated my question based on your suggestion.  Still doesn't work for me.  Mind taking a look and seeing if there is just a simple mistake?

Comment: It is hard to know what is the problem without a minimal working example of your problem. Please provide some working code that anyone can execute.

Comment: Sorry to bump up such an old tread, but interesting, it seams the updated reactive value `plotReady$ok` is noticed and processed without first finishing the observeEvent body... How does this work? It is running sequencial right...?

Comment: The button will be disabled as soon as `Shinyjs::disable` is called. This is because `shinyjs` performs a direct execution using `JS` on the browser side, therefore the changes are immediate. The R code, that is working on the server side, will be executed sequentially, and changes in reactive values will be notified to other reactive functions after the `observeEvent` finishes, after that, the plot will be updated.

Comment: Note that while R is working (simulated in the code with a `Sys.sleep`), the plot is going to be disabled by the browser until the server side finishes processing, as long as I know, this is by design and implemented by the JS components of `Shiny` alone, not `shinyJS`.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have installed and included the shinyjs package in your Shiny app:
`install.packages("shinyjs")`
`library(shinyjs)`

Mind that calling `shinyjs::disable(id)` in the server.R file is not
sufficient to disable an input or element. You should also add the line
`shinyjs::useShinyjs()` in the ui.R file to enable the use of the
shinyjs package and see the magic happen.

In your ui.R file:
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(), # Required to enable shinyjs functionality
  ... Rest of your UI code
)
```

Maybe the thread is old but this can still be helpful!

Comment: Thanks! The solution posted by @Geovany did not work until I added your "shinyjs::useShinyjs()," code.